# How to return object value by key in php?

Tags: php

I feel insane for asking this, but I just can't find an answer to this very simple question.

I have an object:
print_r:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [formkey] => 1F9trPeu9DA4W0CjADN4a1fl3Jh682ZPF8remWB21RhI
    [draftResponse] => []
    [pageHistory] => 0
    [entry.358412101] => asdf
    [entry.898829644] => asdf
    [entry.2071756716] => asdf
    [entry.958924423] => asdf
)
```

var_dump:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (7) {
  ["formkey"]=>
  string(44) "1F9trPeu9DA4W0CjADN4a1fl3Jh682ZPF8remWB21RhI"
  ["draftResponse"]=>
  string(2) "[]"
  ["pageHistory"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["entry.358412101"]=>
  string(4) "asdf"
  ["entry.898829644"]=>
  string(4) "asdf"
  ["entry.2071756716"]=>
  string(4) "asdf"
  ["entry.958924423"]=>
  string(4) "asdf"
}
```

I want to return a single value. I this is what thought you were suppose to do:

```
return($objData['formkey']);
```

but this returns PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array. What am I doing wrong?

I post the data as a json-objec to the server and then it converts it like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$objData = json_decode($data);
```

Comment: If your array a object try with `return $objData->formkey;`?

Comment: See the error.log for more information

Comment: `return $objData->formkey;`

Comment: you might want to share the code where array is being initialized since by just looking at array dump would be difficult to answer $objData may be an object.

Comment: A "500 error" is in fact an error with a sensible title, but it is being kept from you by your web server for security reasons. Check your PHP or Apache logs.

Comment: Btw, that's an object, not an array. See @Dagon's answer.

Comment: Also, try executing the PHP script from the console - you may get more error info that way.

Comment: the current suggestions don't work, I said array, that was wrong on my part.

Comment: what's the error? `500 error` isn't useful here.

Comment: @PineappleUndertheSea question updated!

Comment: return $objData->formkey; returns empty.

Comment: "500" just means that the PHP script failed and did not output specific errors because its error reporting is turned off, so Apache responds with the only thing it can: 500, server error. Figure out how to turn on visible error reporting *or* figure out where your logs are and check them. The specific error is being reported *somewhere*. Taking "500" as the only answer without prodding further is just poking in the dark.

Comment: After `json_decode`, `var_dump($objData);` what you get?

Comment: I updated the error to a more percise one.

Answer (score 2):

The `[key]` syntax is for accessing an entry in an `array`.

As you can see from the dump, you have an `Object`. Object properties are accessed with `->key`.

```
return $objData->formkey;
```

If you want to see error messages check the log files, or enable reporting: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: If I console.log(data) i get an empty string when doing that?

Comment: @Kristoffer Why would you `console.log` data in Javascript for a PHP problem?

Comment: because I post using ajax.

Comment: @Kristoffer But between *PHP code, ???, problem, ???, `console.log`* are about three gazillion more steps which may each cause an error. You can't debug a PHP problem client-side in Javascript. Focus on the PHP code first.

Comment: I assume you have an empty response. But it's impossible to tell as you haven't posted any related code...

Comment: I had a solution before where I posted using a regular form , the problems ocured when I tried to catch the post that I did with Ajax.

Comment: Yes, e.g.: you could drive your app with test data, `$data = "{..json data..}";`, that would completely eliminate the need to do ajax calls.